# Haskell get character array from string?

Tags: haskell

Is it possible if given a string I could get each character composing that string?

Comment: Yes. I think that strings are list of char in Haskell.

Comment: What do you want to do with the characters?

Comment: Yes, the function is called `id`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Haskell, strings are just (linked) lists of characters; you can find the line

```
type String = [Char]
```

somewhere in the source of every Haskell implementation. That makes tasks such as finding the first occurence of a certain character (`elemIndex 'a' mystring`) or calculating the frequency of each character (`map (head &&& length) . group . sort`) trivial.

Because of this, you can use the usual syntax for lists with strings, too. Actually, `"foo"` is just sugar for `['f','o','o']`, which in turn is just sugar for `'f' : 'o' : 'o' : []`. You can pattern match, map and fold on them as you like. For instance, if you want to get the element at position `n` of `mystring`, you could use `mystring !! n`, provided that `0 <= n < length mystring`.

Comment: `map sum . group . sort` is ill-typed for strings. Perhaps you meant something like `map (head &&& length) . group . sort`?

Comment: So say I passed a string in as a parameter to a function, how would I actually access each char? using map?

Comment: @FUZxxl, what happens if you're using an abstract data type, which is not technically a string, but is a string..... how do you get the characters then?

Comment: @user997112 I don't understand your question. Except some esoteric extensions to Haskell, anything declared as `"abc"` or of type `String` or equally `[Char]` is a String as described above.

Comment: @FUXxxl he means `newtype String2 = String2 String`, but not exporting the constructor, I think

Answer (score 15):

Well, the question does say he wants an array:

```
import Data.Array
stringToArray :: String -> Array
stringToArray s = listArray (0, length s - 1) s
```

Comment: This is what I came looking for. In fact, this is the *correct* answer to the question, even if it wasn't what the OP intended.

Answer (score 7):

The `string` type is just an [alias](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#t:String) for `[Char]` so you don't need to do anything.

```
Prelude> tail "Hello"
"ello"
Prelude> ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
"Hello"
Prelude> "Hello" !! 4
'o'
```