# How to convert a string to an array containing each character in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I was looking at this post here:
[Haskell get character array from string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8042170/haskell-get-character-array-from-string)

I see it says that in haskell strings are essentially arrays containing each letter, but I was wondering; how would I turn the format from the string to an array of individual components, for example:

```
["ABCD","EFGH"]
```

to

```
[["A","B","C","D"],["E","F","G","H"]]
```

I'd like to know a method without using any external imports.

Comment: Do you know how to turn `'A'` into `"A"`?

Comment: Strings are lists of Char, not arrays.   And `["E","F","G","H"]` is a list of String, not an array.  Just to avoid future confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap each element in a singleton list, so:

```
map (map pure) ["ABCD", "EFGH"] :: [[String]]
```

this then produces:

```
Prelude> map (map pure) ["ABCD", "EFGH"] :: [[String]]
[["A","B","C","D"],["E","F","G","H"]]
```

That being said, a `String` is simply a list of `Char`s, indeed:

```
type String = [Char]
```

so if you just want to work with a list of `Char`s, you can simply work with the string directly. By converting it to a list of list of `String`s, we know that all these strings contain *one* `Char`, but that is no longer guaranteed by the type.