# How to create a function that returns True or False if a list is inside another list? Example: [1,2] [4,3,1,2] True

Tags: haskell

I want to create a function that returns True or False if a list is inside another list, for example `['a','b'] ['c','d','a','b'] -> True`

I created that function but it only works with numbers. If I use a list of characters (String) it just doesn't work.

```
check x y = aux x x y

aux _ _ [] = False
aux _ [] _ = True
aux x (h:t) (j:k)
 |h==j= aux x t k
 |otherwise= aux x x k
```

If I try `check [1,2] [1,3,1,5,1,2,7]` works perfectly but if I try `check "ab" "cdab"` it returns false even though there is "cdAB".

Edit: I fixed it, I just switched the base case

check x y = aux x x y

```
aux _ [] _ = True
aux _ _ [] = False
aux x (h:t) (j:k)
 |h==j= aux x t k
 |otherwise= aux x x k
```

Comment: There appears to be some insight here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8042170/102937

Comment: `check [1,2] [1,3,1,2]` returns `False` as well, the difference is not that it works for `Char`s/`Int`s, but the algorithm makes not much sense. Can you explain why you use `x` here?

Comment: Take a look at how [`isSuffixOf`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/src/Data-OldList.html#isSuffixOf) is implemented for a simple quadratic algorithm. You can also try to implement a (functional version) of the [*Knuth - Morris - Pratt algorithm*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm).

Comment: [*What should I do when someone answers my question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

The analogous call to `check [1,2] [1,3,1,5,1,2,7]` is not `check "ab" "cdab"`, but rather `check "ab" "acaeabg"`. Similarly, the analogous call to `check "ab" "cdab"` is not `check [1,2] [1,3,1,5,1,2,7]` but `check [1,2] [3,4,1,2]`. If you compare analogous calls, you will see that it has nothing to do with numbers vs. characters:

```
> (check [1,2] [1,3,1,5,1,2,7], check "ab" "acaeabg")
(True, True)
> (check [1,2] [3,4,1,2], check "ab" "cdab")
(False, False)
```

To find the real problem, here is the actual sequence of queries I tried that enlightened me:

```
> check "" "cdab"
True
> check "b" "cdab"
False
> check "b" "b"
False
> check "" ""
False
```

Hopefully this gives you two things: a flavor of what it looks like to do debugging in Haskell (keep making your inputs smaller until they either start returning the right thing, in which case back up and try again, or can't be made smaller) and a big hint about one of the problems in your implementation.

But don't stop once you've found the first problem! You'll want to write a nice big collection of tests; are there any other problems with your implementation?